# How to increase/decrease size of this heart shape in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw heart shape in html 5 canvas. I know a mathematical equation that generates coordinates on heart shape. I have implemented those equations in javascript function and that functions is returning coordinates. Everything is working properly and heart is drawn on canvas. But heart shape size is fixed. I have tried many things to increase its size but none of them work. Can you help me in changing something in equation to get desired size?

Here is equations:-

x = 16 sin(t) * sin(t) * sin(t)

y = 13 cos(t) - 5 cos(2t) - 2 cos(3t) - cos(4t)

I don't know how to show power in this editor so i multiplied sin(t) three times.

Here is javascript function:-

```
function getCordinatesOnHeartShape(x, y) {
    var cordinates = [];
    var pi = Math.PI;
    for(var t = 0; t <= 360; t++) {
        var tr = (t * pi)/180;
        cordinates[t] = {
            x : (x - (16 * Math.sin(tr) * Math.sin(tr) * Math.sin(tr))),
            y : (y -((13 * Math.cos(tr)) - (5 * Math.cos(2 * tr)) - (2 * Math.cos(3 * tr)) - Math.cos(4 * tr)))
        };
    }
    return cordinates;
}
```

Here is how i drawn heart on canvas at position (200, 200):-

```
ctx.beginPath();
var hc = getCordinatesOnHeartShape(200, 200);
for(var i = 0; i < hc.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(hc[i].x, hc[i].y);
}
ctx.fill();
```

This draw a fixed size heart on position (200, 200) and i want change it's size. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your formula. Now you can change the value of r to change the size of your heart.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 300),
    cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 300),
    cy = ch / 2;

//////////////////
let r = 5; // change this!
/////////////////

function getCordinatesOnHeartShape(x, y) {
  var cordinates = [];
  var pi = Math.PI;
  for (var t = 0; t <= 360; t++) {
    var tr = t * pi / 180;
    cordinates[t] = {
      x: x - 16 * r * Math.sin(tr) * Math.sin(tr) * Math.sin(tr),
      y:
      y -
      (13 * r * Math.cos(tr) -
       5 * r * Math.cos(2 * tr) -
       2 * r * Math.cos(3 * tr) -
       r * Math.cos(4 * tr))
    };
  }
  return cordinates;
}

ctx.beginPath();
var hc = getCordinatesOnHeartShape(200, 200);
for (var i = 0; i < hc.length; i++) {
  ctx.lineTo(hc[i].x, hc[i].y);
}
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using Canvas `ctx.save()`, `ctx.restore()` and `ctx.translate()` functions.

here is the full code.

i hope this helps you.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
let canvasWidth = canvas.width;
let canvasHeight = canvas.height;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function getCordinatesOnHeartShape(x, y) {
  var cordinates = [];
  var pi = Math.PI;
  for (var t = 0; t <= 360; t++) {
    var tr = (t * pi) / 180;
    cordinates[t] = {
      x: (x - (16 * Math.sin(tr) * Math.sin(tr) * Math.sin(tr))),
      y: (y - ((13 * Math.cos(tr)) - (5 * Math.cos(2 * tr)) - (2 * Math.cos(3 * tr)) - Math.cos(4 * tr)))
    };
  }

  return cordinates;
}

let size = 1;
let a = 0;

let x = 100;
let y = 100;

function animate() {
  a += 0.05;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(-canvasWidth / 2, -canvasHeight / 2, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  size = 2 - Math.cos(a);
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.translate(x, y);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  var hc = getCordinatesOnHeartShape(x, y);
  ctx.translate(-size * x, -size * y);
  ctx.scale(size, size);
  for (var i = 0; i < hc.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(hc[i].x, hc[i].y);
  }
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();


  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Heart</title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to animate. For just size increase/decrease, solution from @enxaneta is easier. Thanks again, its gave me further ideas to create awesome.

Comment: Yes I totally understand and agree with @enxaneta's solution. Keep up the work.